# NativeScript TabView Navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, navigation, nativescript, tabview

I am creating an app starting from the NativeScript TabView template app (https://github.com/NativeScript/template-tab-navigation-ng), and I can't figure out how to programmatically navigate to a page within a page-router-outlet from AppComponent. Example:

```
export class AppComponent{

    constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private currentRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

    getIconSource(icon: string): string {
        const iconPrefix = isAndroid ? "res://" : "res://tabIcons/";
        return iconPrefix + icon;
    }

    navigateToPage(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['../page'], { relativeTo: this.currentRoute });
    }
}
```

This works fine from within a page inside the page-router-outlet, but when I call it from AppComponent, I get a console error such as this:

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'page'
```

My actual code is here: https://github.com/rchisholm/saint_stan

My actual full error is here, from the debugging console:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'novena-day/1' ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'novena-day/1' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'novena-day/1'
```

My attempted navigation is inside of a LocalNotifications.addOnMessageReceivedCallback in OnInit in AppComponent.

This seems like it should be simple. I am a bit new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the latest versions of NativeScript, TypeScript, and Angular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you navigate to some TabView tab. Your outlets have to be set in app.routing.ts file.

```
private navigateToFoo() {
    this.routerExtensions.navigate([
        '/YourTabRouting', { outlets: { fooOutlet: ['foo'] } }
    ])
}
```

Comment: How do i set up outlets in app-routing.module.ts? My paths are set up like this:
`{ path: "pageOne", component: PageOneComponent, outlet: "tabOne" }`

Comment: ("pageOne" being a page within my outlet "tabOne")

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mrisek, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @RussellChisholm, don't forget to upwote the answer if you find it useful.